# Animate from 1st page to 3rd page in PageView flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a phone number login & signup flow for an app. I want to animate to a particular page in PageView when certain condition is met. Say when a user is registered I would go to OtpInput Screen else go to SignUp Screen.

I have used PageView with list of Screens for it as children. And a controller and animateToPage() function which has animation defined.

I expect that the page animate to 3rd Page in the list directly but it animates to 3rd Page through 2nd Page. I need it to animate to 3rd page without going through 2nd Page.